# Kafka consumer api (no zookeeper configuration)

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using Kafka client library comes with Kafka 0.11.0.1. I noticed that using kafkaconsumer does not need to configure zookeeper anymore. Does that mean zookeep server will automatically be located by the kafka bootstrap server?

Comment: i think is because you don't need to interact with zookeeper at all, so the guys working on kafka don't want the users messing around directly with zookeeper.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918065/why-do-kafka-consumers-connect-to-zookeeper-and-producers-get-metadata-from-bro
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-657

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Kafka 0.9 the KafkaConsumer implementation stores offsets commit and consumer group information in Kafka brokers themselves. This eliminates the zookeeper dependency and increases the scalability of the consumers.