# Consume kafka from brokers?

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue, apache-zookeeper, hadoop2

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --topic test

./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 127.0.0.1:9092 --topic test
```

Why to consume kakfa needed zookeeper?
could I consume kafka from brokers ?

Comment: Here is your Answer. Please read it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918065/why-do-kafka-consumers-connect-to-zookeeper-and-producers-get-metadata-from-bro

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--zookeeper` is an outdated option (for the old Consumer).

Use the newer `--bootstrap-server` option with `kafka-console-consumer`.

More info: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#newconsumerconfigs

Comment: Thanks for the answer